# glyphicon input wrong bootstrap angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a little problem, When I want to externalize my input, the position of my glyphicon is wrong but I don't know why.

```
<div class="form-group"
                         ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback': comment_fields.$submitted && comment_fields.test.$invalid }">
                        <input-test  model-ua="$ctrl.test"></input-test>
                         <span ng-show="comment_fields.$submitted && comment_fields.test.$invalid"
                               class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the glyphicon is in a different position on the page?

Comment: Yes, I change my metohd why transclude in ng class ifControl.$submitted but doesn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a position placement issue with the glyphicon I would suggest adding this CSS:

```
glyphicon-remove:before{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
}
```

You will have to play around with the top and left positions to get it where you need.

Comment: thanks the position is good !  but I have an other problem with the externalisation. I have this : <input-global  if-label="test" if-control="comment_field" if-input-name="test"></input-global>                                                               and in my global template : <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback': ctrl.ifControl.$submitted && $ctrl.ifControl.$ctrl.ifInputName.$invalid}">                                                 The data binding doesn't work

Comment: @coco62 let me take a look at it and let you know.